# prevent moon key on a Sun keyboard from shutting down my gentoo PC

Tags: keyboard, gentoo, shutdown

I have a Sun keyboard attached to my gentoo PC.  If I accidentally touch the key with the moon symbol on it (happens once or twice a week as I am reaching for my mouse), it triggers an orderly shutdown of my PC.

I want to stop it from doing that.

My first attempt was to deactivate the `ca` entry in `/etc/inittab` by changing it to
`ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/bin/true /sbin/shutdown -h now "Fist of Bob"`
but the moon key still shuts down the PC.

This PC does not have an `/etc/acpi` directory as referenced in  [Have Sun keyboard moon key (116) not shut down my computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59179/have-sun-keyboard-moon-key-116-not-shut-down-my-computer), nor does it have `systemd`.

I have no idea what chain of events is triggered by pressing the moon key, so I have no idea what software I should be reconfiguring to prevent the shutdown.

Comment: what does this have to do with the problem? ... `while reaching for my mouse`

Comment: The moon key is near my mouse, and the only reason my hand goes near the moon key is when I'm reaching for my mouse.